# Calculate hour and pay

Tags: php, html

ok im stuck at how to calculate the pay. for example how would i calculate 14 hours and 42mins * Pay Salary

i tried this 14.42 * 15 = 216.3 but im pretty sure thats off by a few cents or dollars. Any idea how to go about it

Comment: just use the smallest unit... in this case either minutes or seconds

Comment: The equation you want is `(H + (m / 60)) * P = Salary`

Comment: .42 hours is not 42 minutes.

Answer (score 5):

Since there are 60 minutes in an hour, and not 100, 14.42 isn't 14 hours and 42 mins, but rather 14 hours and 25 minutes.

To get the proper number in hours, you should be doing: `$hours + ($minutes / 60)`.

However, **DON'T DO THAT**.

If you follow this logic, you are making calculations with floats, which can lead to **unexpected results**.

ALWAYS use the smallest **integer** unit. In your case, you want to do the calculation with minutes AND cents of dollars (and not dollars!)
For example:

```
$worktime = $hours * 60 + $minutes;
$salary = 1540; // = $15.40 -> in cents!
$pay = $worktime * $salary; // This result is in cents
```

You will always store the integer `$pay` (cents value) in the database (in an integer column!), and use it for calculations. You will display it in dollar, with decimals, only at the end, while displaying the result on screen.

Answer (score 1):

You're forgetting that `1h = 60m`, so doing `14.42` is incorrect, since `14h42m` should be `14 + (42/60) = 14.7` hours.

This would mean that you need to do:

```
14.7 * 15 = 220.5
```